# ORA-39244:Event to disable dropping null bit image header during relational select

Tags: oracle, impdp

I was trying to import a dump file using IMPDP command and has end up with the following errors:

```
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01 for user user1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 798
ORA-39244: Event to disable dropping null bit image header during relational select
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 86
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPC$QUE_INT", line 1825
ORA-04063: package body "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS" has errors
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS"
```

I have searched on oracle forums and google for any solution. Not sure why this error is happening. Is this related to the db configuration?

Comment: Which user are you trying to import as? Also, OS and Oracle DB version are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For me this line seems most telling:

```
PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "SYS.DBMS_AQADM_SYS"
```

You should check to see if the user that you exported had a job scheduled using a program owned by someone else. If so you are trying to schedule a job for a program that does not exist. You can create the program, then do the import as long as the user who will own the program exists before you create the program as that user.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But the issue get resolved when I re-installed the database. Don't know what was the issue.